# Deliver intent for a tab activity to the main activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabactivity

I am writing a tab using SomeActivity extends TabActivity.
Here is the main process:
The main activity will call the SomeActivity. And the SomeActivity will put two activity (activityone and activitytwo) to the two tabs.
Here is my question, when the subactivity of the SomeActivity has finished, how could I pass the intent with some extra to the mainactivity?

Here is the main code of SomeActivity, which will be called by the MainActivity.

```
public class SomeActivity extends TabActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

  //TAB1
    intent = new Intent(this,ActivityOne.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
    .setIndicator("Tab1", res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play))
    .setContent(intent);//
    tabHost.addTab(spec);//

    //TAB2
    intent = new Intent(this,ActivityTwo.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
    .setIndicator("Tab1", res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play))
    .setContent(intent);//
    tabHost.addTab(spec);//

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

Here is where I want to send an intent to the MainActivity.

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity{
    private void SendIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("information", "someinformation");

        // Set result and finish this Activity
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: would you like to add some code you have done with

Comment: is this clear enough to express myself?

Comment: `TabActivity` has been deprecated for over two years. Please use more modern solutions for tabs: `FragmentTabHost`, action bar tabs, `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip`).